# Rendering image to Bitmap from 3D model from model3dgroup fail

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using C# WPF and I'm trying to render a 2D view from a 3D model that I could use as a preview image for my ui items.

To accomplish that I'm trying to use properly this class:

**RenderTargetBitmap Class**(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is how I try to use it :

**Irrelevant since update**

```
public void SetModelImage()
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        Viewport3D myViewport3d = new Viewport3D();
        ModelVisual3D myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
        Model3DGroup myModel3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();
        GeometryModel3D myGeometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();
        this.previewModel = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        PerspectiveCamera myPCamera = new PerspectiveCamera();

        myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(this.content);// ajoute le modele
        myModelVisual3D.Content = myModel3DGroup;
        myModelVisual3D.Content = this.content;
        myViewport3d.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);
        bmp.Render(myViewport3d);

        this.previewModel.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        string filepath = "C:\\Users\\Remi\\Desktop\\toto.png";
        using (Stream stm = File.Create(filepath))
        {

            this.previewModel.Save(stm);

        }

    }
```

The **problem** is that the generated **Bitpmap is totaly black**.

Full file pastbin:
http://paste.isomorphis.me/jgz

Thanks for your time ! :)

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to an advice I've corrected the way I was initializing the layout with `measure` `arrange` and `InvalidateVisual` but I still have a black bitmap generated.
[image]

Comment: Did you find out how to create a non-black .png out of the 3D-model?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run an initial layout of the `Viewport3D` element by calling its `Measure` and `Arrange` methods. You may also need to call `InvalidateVisual`.

```
myViewport3d.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);
myViewport3d.Measure(new Size(200, 200));
myViewport3d.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200));
myViewport3d.InvalidateVisual();
bmp.Render(myViewport3d);
```

Comment: Still not with InvalidateVisual()

Post and screenshot updated, thanks !